# AWS: Layer code not found when using "sam invoke local"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm working on a sample AWS project that creates two lambda functions. These functions share common code from `node_modules` which has been placed in a separate layer (specifically `AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion`, not `AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion`). I can deploy this code and it works correctly when I test the deployed version.

However, when I try to test the code locally using `sam invoke local`, the common code is not found. I get this error (I'm trying to use the npm package "axios"):

> `{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'axios'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/get-timezone.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js"}`

This is my `template.yaml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: AWS Sample

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 30

Resources:
  SampleCommonLayer:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs12.x
      Content: nodejs.zip
      Description: Sample Common LayerVersion
      LayerName: SampleCommonLayer

  GetTimezoneFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: dist/get-timezone
      Handler: get-timezone.getTimezone
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Layers:
        - !Ref SampleCommonLayer
      Events:
        GetTimezone:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /get-timezone
            Method: get

  ReverseFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: dist/reverse
      Handler: reverse.reverse
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Layers:
        - !Ref SampleCommonLayer
      Events:
        Reverse:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /reverse
            Method: get

Outputs:
  GetTimezoneApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for getTimezone function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/get-timezone/"
  GetTimezoneFunction:
    Description: "getTimezone Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt GetTimezoneFunction.Arn
  GetTimezoneFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for getTimezone function"
    Value: !GetAtt GetTimezoneFunctionRole.Arn

  ReverseApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for reverse function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/reverse/"
  ReverseFunction:
    Description: "reverse Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt ReverseFunction.Arn
  ReverseFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for reverse function"
    Value: !GetAtt ReverseFunctionRole.Arn
```

I'm invoking the GetTimezone function like this:

`sam local invoke --layer-cache-basedir layer-cache --force-image-build \"GetTimezoneFunction\" --event events/event-timezone.json -d 5858`

Nothing ever gets copied into the `layer-cache` directory, and I'm sure that's part of the problem, but I can't figure out how I'd fix that.

I've searched for answers to this problem, but so far I've only found unanswered questions, or answers that don't match my particular situation.

Most of the somewhat-related questions involve `AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion`, not `AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion`. I've tried using `Serverless` instead, but that hasn't helped.

**UPDATE:**

If I change...

```
      Layers:
        - !Ref SampleCommonLayer
```

...to...

```
      Layers:
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:layer:SampleCommonLayer:y
```

...using an already-deployed layer (where `xxxxxxxxxxxx` and `y` are a specific ID and version) then `sam local invoke` works. But I don't want to use something I have to deploy first, I want to use the latest local not-yet-deployed code.

Comment: I have the exact same issue! Did you find a solution to your problem? I wasted a whole day to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I think that this is an issue in the SAM CLI so I opened an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/2016).

Comment: Unfortunately not. I haven't worked on AWS for a while since first posting this question, but when I get back to doing more AWS work, I sure hope someone has fixed this.

Comment: It's extremely frustrating the AWS hasn't fixed this for ~2 years now...

Answer (score 4):

This is known issue: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/947

Currently the "workaround" is to use the directory of the layer instead of a zip file.

Comment: I haven't worked with the project where I originally ran into this issue for months, so the details are a bit fuzzy now. Does this workaround solve the sam-local-invoke problem, but break deployment? I can't remember now if deploying a layer using a .zip file was mandatory or optional.

Comment: As far as I know it makes no difference if the layer is in a zip file or a directory. I just tried it and it worked the same as with my zip file.

Comment: Yep, pointing the Layer `ContentUri` parameter to a directory doesn't fix the issue...

Comment: Note that for Java, `ContentUri` **must** be a zip file. I used a directory, and it isn't supported for Java. See working example here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/s3-java/template.yml#L43